# Fetching local notifications in iOS and display in the app

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am implementing a feature where in we will be scheduling local notifications. So far, I have followed all the document and seems to work fine i.e

- if the app is in the background / foreground i do get the notifications.

however, I also need to display all the notifications that have occurred inside alerts section of the app after it comes to the foreground, so that in case the user had snoozed / closed the alerts, he could take actions on the notification when listed in the alerts.

Is there a way I could fetch all the notifications that were fired when the app was in the background ?

Answer (score 0):

Not from the application, it can only tell you about future (or future repeating) notifications.

You should keep a record of the notifications that you are scheduling and which have been triggered (used to open the app or received while in the foreground) so you can display an appropriate list.

Comment: Got that.. so i need to handle that internally within the app and list them. Just was wondering if there could be an implicit handling.. Thank you :-)